# FileNotFoundException with weblogic server

Tags: java, web-services, tomcat, weblogic, rmi

I am using some third party code which is actually a web service client. It works fine when I run it simply on JDK or even on `Tomcat`. But as soon as I integrated it in my web project for production phase with `weblogic` server, it started to act abnormally with an error `FileNotFoundException` which I haven't been able to solve.
As far as I understand `Tomcat` is for development phases and therefore sort of lenient, that's why I didn't encounter any problem earlier. But `weblogic`adds restrictions in its own way.
If I am unable to run that web service client on `weblogic`, I need to keep this piece of code outside the production server environment and run it on simple JDK. Now to access this external code, should I need to use `Remote Method Invocation` or is there any simpler solution? I have added full stack trace just by replacing actual URL with `WEBSERVICEURL`. Hope this wouldn't affect the answers.

```
Exception in thread "Timer-5" javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException: Failed to access the WSDL at: https://cert.hub.care360.com/orders/submission/service?wsdl. It failed with: 
    Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url: 'WEBSERVICEURL'.
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.tryWithMex(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:172)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:153)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:273)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:236)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:184)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:42)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSProvider.java:206)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:57)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:41)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.medplus.orders.OrderSubmissionService.<init>(OrderSubmissionService.java:42)
    at com.adamsoft.edoc.util.QuestOrderService.sendOrder(QuestOrderService.java:137)
    at com.adamsoft.edoc.util.QuestOrderService.run(QuestOrderService.java:308)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:512)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:462)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: Response: '401: Unauthorized' for url: 'WEBSERVICEURL'
    at weblogic.net.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:474)
    at weblogic.net.http.SOAPHttpsURLConnection.getInputStream(SOAPHttpsURLConnection.java:37)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1010)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.createReader(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:843)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.resolveWSDL(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:289)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.wsdl.parser.RuntimeWSDLParser.parse(RuntimeWSDLParser.java:138)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.parseWSDL(WSServiceDelegate.java:273)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:237)
    at com.sun.xml.ws.client.WSServiceDelegate.<init>(WSServiceDelegate.java:187)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSServiceDelegate.java:36)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider$ServiceDelegate.<init>(WLSProvider.java:207)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:57)
    at weblogic.wsee.jaxws.spi.WLSProvider.createServiceDelegate(WLSProvider.java:41)
    at javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Service.java:56)
    at com.medplus.orders.OrderSubmissionService.<init>(OrderSubmissionService.java:43)
    at com.adamsoft.edoc.util.QuestOrderService.sendOrder(QuestOrderService.java:137)
    at com.adamsoft.edoc.util.QuestOrderService.run(QuestOrderService.java:310)
    ... 2 more
```

Comment: Looks like a classpath issue?

Comment: What sort of error is being thrown (full stack)? Ths fix is probably pretty easy but there is not enough information to help